# Why is the async function not working while fetching MAM data?

Tags: iota-network, tangle, masked-authenticated-messaging, attach-to-tangle

I am making a simple MAM publish and fetch script. The first script is **mam_publish** which publishes the data. The other script is **mam_receive** which fetched the already published data.

Now, the problem is that publishing script is working correctly but fetch script is not fetching the data. It is only executing the line

```
console.log('\n\nFETCHING DATA!!\n\n')
```

I tried debugging the code, but I am unable to figure out the problem. Can someone take a look?

Here is the script for **mam_publish.js**

```
const Mam = require('@iota/mam')
const { asciiToTrytes } = require('@iota/converter')
const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js');
const mode = 'restricted'
const secretKey = 'VERYSECRETKEY'
const provider = 'https://nodes.devnet.iota.org'

let numberofSteps;
let kilometersWalked;

let mamState = Mam.init(provider)
// Set channel mode
mamState = Mam.changeMode(mamState, mode, secretKey)

const publish = async packet => {
        // Create MAM Payload - STRING OF TRYTES
        const trytes = asciiToTrytes(packet)
        const message = Mam.create(mamState, trytes)
         // Save new mamState
        mamState = message.state
         // Attach the payload
        await Mam.attach(message.payload, message.address, 3, 9)
        console.log('Published', packet, '\n');
        console.log ('Root', message.root);
        //return message.root
    }

const publishAll = async () => {
  const root = await publish({
    numberofSteps: Math.floor((Math.random()*89)+10),
    kilometersWalked: (numberofSteps/1312.335),
    message: 'Message from Alice',
    timestamp: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
  })

  await publish({
    numberofSteps: Math.floor((Math.random()*89)+10),
    kilometersWalked: (numberofSteps/1312.335),
    message: 'Message from Alice',
    timestamp: (new Date()).toLocaleString()
  })
  return root
}
publishAll()
```

and the script for **mam_receive**

```
const Mam = require('./lib/mam.client.js');
const { trytesToAscii } = require('@iota/converter')
const IOTA = require('iota.lib.js');
const mode = 'restricted'
const secretKey = 'VERYSECRETKEY'
const provider = 'https://nodes.devnet.iota.org'

let root = 'SBOKXANECLJFR9QHUARPNFKJKRCEEQ9YACINNUPNOVTLZJCLUZN9ANTHZAATNCYLZGMVVVOBAUETPAHOZ';

// Initialise MAM State
let mamState = Mam.init(provider);
mamState = Mam.changeMode(mamState, mode, secretKey)


const logData = data => console.log('Fetched and parsed', JSON.parse(trytesToAscii(data)), '\n')


const execute = async root => {
    await Mam.fetch(root, mode, secretKey, logData)
    // Output synchronously once fetch is completed
   const result = await Mam.fetch(root, mode, secretKey)
   result.messages.forEach(message => console.log('Fetched and parsed', JSON.parse(trytesToAscii(message)), '\n'))
    }

console.log('\n\nFETCHING DATA!!\n\n')
execute()
```

Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: your `execute()` function takes a `root` parameter you are not passing... (you probably want to pass the global `root` variable for it). Also probably you want to log your `result` object before iterating over its (possibly empty) messages...

Comment: I tried passing the `root` variable in `execute()` function, but the result is same. By logging `result` you mean use `console.log()`?

Comment: yes, console.log :)

Comment: I tried making the changes that you suggested, but the result is same. It is still executing `console.log('\n\nFETCHING DATA!!\n\n')` but not executing the execute function even though I passed a root `execute(root)`. Any thing else that I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mam.fetch is not an async function, instead use the callback. You can make any “callback style” function into an async function by wrapping the call in a `return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> ...`. Do a bit of research about Promises, this is a very common and useful pattern in Nodejs.

But i think your problem is secretKey needs to be converted to trytes